# How to turn off css animation at specific breakpoint?

Tags: css, animation

I would like to stop a certain effect that I built in CSS when it gets to mobile.  I know it for jQuery

```
if ( $(window).width() > 766) {}
```

But I have not stumbled onto a css solution.  Here is my animations.

```
@-webkit-keyframes slides{
0%{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
}
100%{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1) translateY(-40%); 
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes Fade{
from{
    opacity: 0;
}
to{
    opacity: 1;
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes up{
from{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
}
to{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-40%);
}
}
```

Comment: I think it's appropriate to delete it, yes. Since you were able to find the solution in a matter of minutes, so can others. Leaving it open won't do all that much harm other than possible comments, but I think there are no big consequences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
* {
-webkit-animation: none !important;
-moz-animation: none !important;
-ms-animation: none !important;
animation: none !important;
}
}
```